# Read from multiple processes within Java

Tags: java, multithreading, process, polling

I start several bash script processes using the [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class in Java.
How could I structure my program if it should listen to all the outputs the processes are printing to STDOUT. 
The solution should not heavy stressing the CPU.
Should I work with polling over all processes or use a thread for each process and reading InputStream and forwarding it to the presentation thread.

Answer (score 0):

Process class contains following methods: [getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html), [getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29), [getErrorStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29), using these you can redirect your output to STDOUT

Comment: I know how to do it, its more a question about the architecture. One thread for each process reading OutputInputStream or polling the OutputStreams in one single thread. Currently I have implemented the polling approach but it has a high cpu consumption.

Comment: Ok, great that you use a pool. To reduce consumption SDK recommends: "*It is a good idea for the returned ____ stream to be buffered*". Another trick - try use BufferedReader#readLine - so console output will not be printed immediately, but right after '\n' symbol. Don't forget flush last line if it has no '\n'